# Collapse large number of rows into scrollable view

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with a header, followed by a large number of rows, then a row with some aggregates on that data for each column at the bottom (sums, averages, etc.). The aggregate row at the bottom is not very discoverable; you have to scroll past all the data first. I would like to collapse the data rows into a scrollable view, ~20 rows, so that the header shows, then only 20 rows show, then the aggregate row shows, and you can scroll within those 20 rows to see all the data but the size and position of the view remains the same.

Comment: Well you can't because this is not a feature of Google Sheets. Not really programming, either; this kind of questions belong on [webapps.se]

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't have a "collapse/expand" feature but it has "hide/show" and also has Filters and Filter Views.